# argparse fails when called from unittest test

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, python-unittest

In a file (say `parser.py`) I have:

```
import argparse

def parse_cmdline(cmdline=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--first-param',help="Does foo.")
    parser.add_argument('--second-param',help="Does bar.")

    if cmdline is not None:
        args = parser.parse_args(cmdline)
    else:
        args = parser.parse_args()

    return vars(args)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print parse_cmdline()
```

Sure enough, when called from the command line it works and give me pretty much what I expect:

```
$ ./parser.py --first-param 123 --second-param 456
{'first_param': '123', 'second_param': '456'}
```

But then I want to `unittest` it, thus I write a `test_parser.py` file:

```
import unittest
from parser import parse_cmdline

class TestParser(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_parse_cmdline(self):
        parsed = parse_cmdline("--first-param 123 --second-param 456")

        self.assertEqual(parsed['first_param'],'123')
        self.assertEqual(parsed['second_param'],'456')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then I get the following error:

```
usage: test_parser.py [-h] [--first-param FIRST_PARAM]
                      [--second-param SECOND_PARAM]
test_parser.py: error: unrecognized arguments: - - f i r s t - p a r a m   1 2 3   - - s e c o n d - p a r a m   4 5 6
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_parse_cmdline (__main__.TestParser)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_parser.py", line 8, in test_parse_cmdline
    parsed = parse_cmdline("--first-param 123 --second-param 456")
  File "/home/renan/test_argparse/parser.py", line 12, in parse_cmdline
    args = parser.parse_args(cmdline)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1691, in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2361, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2349, in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

As can be seen, the command line I specified (`--first-param 123 --second-param 456`) became 
`- - f i r s t - p a r a m   1 2 3   - - s e c o n d - p a r a m   4 5 6` (each character is separated by a space).

I don't understand why: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`argparse` wants an "argument vector"—that is, a list of separate arguments—not a "command line" string.

And just calling `split` won't solve things. For example, this command line from the shell:

```
python script.py --first-param '123 456' --second-param 789
```

… will correctly give you `123 456` and `789`, but this line of code:

```
parse_cmdline("--first-param '123 456' --second-param 789")
```

will not; it will give you `'123` and `789`, with an extra `456'` that it doesn't know how to deal with.

In fact, even this is wrong:

```
parse_cmdline("--first-param '123' --second-param 789")
```

… because you'll get `'123'` instead of `123`.

---

There are two ways to deal with this.

First, if you know what you're trying to pass, you can just pass it as a list instead of a string in the first place, and you don't need to worry about fiddly quoting and splitting details:

```
parse_cmdline(["--first-param", "123 456", "--second-param", "789"])
```

Alternatively, if you don't know exactly what you're trying to pass, you just know what it looks like on the shell, you can use [`shlex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
if cmdline is not None:
    args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split(cmdline))
```

… and now Python will split your command line the same way as a standard Unix shell, getting the `123 456` as a single parameter.

Comment: The shlex-based solution is good enough for me right now. Thanks!

Comment: While it is good to keep the distinction between `split` and `shlex` in mind, it does not test `arpgarse` itself.  `test_argparse.py` uses `split` a lot, but does not import `shlex`.  If blanks inside the arguments matter, I would just feed `parse_args` a test list of words.

Answer (score 1):

To answer myself (I realized my mistake a few minutes later):

I am supposed to

```
if cmdline is not None:
    args = parser.parse_args(cmdline.split())
else:
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now the test passes correctly!

Comment: There's a serious problem with this. Try it with `parse_cmdline("--first-param '123 456' --second-param 789")`. That will not do the same thing as if you pass the same thing from the actual shell.

Comment: @abarnert I see; what would be the best solution for this, then?

Comment: It depends on your exact use case. I've written an answer explaining the two standard solutions.

Comment: Yes, in your original case, `parse_args` wraps your test string in `list()`, turning it into a list of individual characters.  Hence the spaces in "- - f i ...".  The comment in the code is 'make sure the args are mutable'.  Evidently it's more concerned with getting a tuple than a string.  Maybe it should object if given a string.