# Testing arguments parsing with unittest and argparse

Tags: python, unit-testing, argparse

I am writing some `unit tests` for my python script. The script allows the user to override a parameter's value.

```
python paramParser.py -d C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m -p 'xxxParamName' -v 20
```

`-d` filename which could contain a parameter name and value
`-p` parameter name
`-v` parameter value

The script reads the file and if the parameter exist in it - it will take its value and write it to another file with its new value.

Running this from the `command-line` successfully overrides the parameter's value.

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
import paramParser

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

  def testOneIntValue(self):
    result = paramParser.main(["-d C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m", "-p 'xxxParamName'", "-v 3"])
    self.assertTrue('xxxParamName.Value= 3', result)

  def testMultipleIntValues(self):
    result = paramParser.main(["-d C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m", "-p 'xxxParamName'", "-v 3"])
    self.assertTrue('[ xxxParamName.Value = [ 1 2 3 ]', result)

  def testTrueBoolean(self):
    result = paramParser.main(["-d C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m", "-p 'xxxParamName'", "-v true"])
    self.assertTrue('xxxParamName.Value = true', result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The tests always pass, any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**
I tried doing the same way as this guy did: [argparse fails when called from unittest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325211/argparse-fails-when-called-from-unittest-test)

```
def testOneValue(self):
    parsed = paramParser.main(["-d","C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m", "-p", "xxxParamName", "-v", "3"])
    self.assertEqual(parsed["d"], "C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m")
    self.assertEqual(parsed["p"], "xxxParamName")
    self.assertEqual(parsed["v"], "3")
```

While his passes (with the help of the [] and seperating the arguments) mine does not. I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Just a quick update about the last issue. I forgot to add a return in my def main(). The tests are now working.

Comment: You're asking the test to evaluate if a non-empty string is truthy, which it **always will be**. Have you read the actual documentation for `unittest`?

Comment: The first parameter to `assertTrue` is an object that can be cast as a `bool`, not a Boolean statement as a string (which is what you are supplying).  Looks like `assertEqual` might be of more use for the first two.

Comment: Look at the `argparse` unittest file for more ideas, `Lib/test/test_argparse.py` - though that's covers more than what your code will need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [`assertTrue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue) statements you are passing a non-empty `string` which always evaluates as `True`.

If `paramParser.main` returns its arguments, you should do something like this:

```
def testOneIntValue(self):
    result = paramParser.main(["-d C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m", "-p 'xxxParamName'", "-v 3 "])
    self.assertEqual(result.xxxParamName, 3)   # access xxxParamName here the way you pass it
```

Also, you might want to read about the [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) module and check out this question - [`How do you write tests for argparse?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160078/how-do-you-write-tests-for-the-argparse-portion-of-a-python-module).

Comment: I tried another way by writing like this:

`def testOneValue(self):
    parsed = paramParser.main(["-d","C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m", "-p", "xxxParamName", "-v", "3"])
    self.assertEqual(parsed["d"], "C:\\Path\\to\\yourfile\\xxx.m")
    self.assertEqual(parsed["p"], "xxxParamName")
    self.assertEqual(parsed["v"], "3")`

but instead i get  `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

This works for another person who(which can be seen in my Edit above)